# How to get Intellisense working on standalone C++ source files in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration, config, visual-studio-2019

Can somebody tell me how to get Intellisense working on standalone C++ source files in Visual Studio 2019 (i.e C++ source files that are not a part of Projects and Solutions). I read online that I need a CppProperties.json file in the directory that my miscellaneous C++ source files and that I can add one by using the Configuration Manager, however it doesn't appear in the contextual dropdown located in the tool bar where it is supposed appear. So I am confused as to what to do to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Just for more context of what I am getting at, this is how my navbar looks like when I open a folder with C++ source files that are not a part of any Projects or Solutions (aka. miscellaneous C++ source files):

[image: A screen shot of the tool bar when I open a folder as the working directory in Visual Studio]

Comment: @AlanBirtles Here is a page from Microsoft's documentation stating it being used for Visual Studio 2019 as well: [Open Folder support for C++ build systems in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/open-folder-projects-cpp?view=msvc-160#configure-code-navigation-with-cpppropertiesjson)

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/open-folder-projects-cpp?view=msvc-160)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I find it funny that you just linked the page I sent as a response to you.

Comment: I suggest that you could put the C++ files in a floder and open the floder in `File->Open->Folder`.

Comment: @BarrnetChou That is exactly how it is right now, I have a folder called C++ for all my miscellaneous C++ Source files, and when I open that folder in Visual Studio, the problem is exactly as I have described above. One thing to note however is that, that folder also has, the compiled executables for the respective C++ source files as well as some other related folders. So, is it necessary for the folder to have only C++ source files and nothing else?

Comment: It is suggested that you could try to put the related C++ files in a folder instead of containing other files in the folder. I tried a lot of situations, all appeared `No Configuration`. If you could provide a minimal example, it will help solve the problem.

Comment: @BarrnetChou

"I tried a lot of situations, all appeared ```No Configuration```. If you could provide a minimal example, it will help solve the problem."

I am confused by what you mean by that, if you could elaborate a bit more, that would be helpful. None the less, I shall try only having the C++ source files in the folder and report back if it was helpful.

Comment: Because I also tried to include other files in a floder or only one file in a floer. However the configuration manager in the navigation bar appeared. I have no way to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @BarrnetChou Is it possible for you to provide a screen shot of all things installed on your installation of Visual Studio 2019? May be I am missing something that need to be installed because I did uncheck some stuff during my first installation that I felt were not necessary for me.

Nvm, your solution worked, well putting the source files in a separate folder, showed me the ```No Configuration``` thing and after some digging, I found that ```vcpkg``` (a package manager for C++ libraries and modules) was the one causing the trouble, getting rid of that, fixed everything! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could put the relevant files in a folder, click `File->Open->Folder` and select a folder containing project files. According to the comments above, it is necessary to get rid of vcpkg.

For example:

[image]

Then, you will find the `Manage Configuration` appears in the navigation bar.

[image]

Here are the screenshots you requested:

[image]

[image]